# How do I change default apps used from the Google drive app on Android 6.0?

Tags: default-applications, google-drive

When I open a file from the Google Drive app for Android (I'm using 6.0 on a OnePlus 3), it uses some internal viewer, and not the system-wide default app. How can I select different apps as default viewers within the Google Drive app?

Examples: use Adobe reader for PDFs, or MX Player for videos.

Comment: I can select other apps of I click "Open With" under the 3 dots, but I'd like it to be automatic when I just click the file

Comment: You can use [better open with](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith) app and set the default as also the time you require to choose it you want select from multiple apps

Comment: @beeshyams I tried the "better open with" app, but it only works for normal files, links, etc., and not within the Google Drive App

Comment: You can try [local storage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ianhanniballake.localstorage), it see the Google drive, but I haven't tried manipulating files on drive

Comment: I have the same problem...